# How can I disable ALL print preview windows in Microsoft Edge OR How can I use Chrome or Firefox as my default app in Windows 10 Pro Kiosk Mode?

Tags: firefox, printing, microsoft-edge, kiosk

On Windows 10 Pro, I want to run kiosk mode with Chrome or Firefox (as I have successfully been able to remove all print dialog boxes from these).  However, I cannot choose either of these applications from the default application menu in the Kiosk Mode Setup (of course all of the windows apps like Edge is there)

Alternatively, I would settle for just using Edge in the Kiosk mode as long as I can disable any and all print preview dialog boxes from the program.  I will need receipts to print out automatically and I don't want the user to be able to see or alter the print settings.

Any help??? Please and thanks!

Comment: With Chromium Edge you can remove Print Preview, but then you need to use the System Print. I am not sure if this will do what you want. ..... https://blogs.msmvps.com/brink/2021/01/05/how-to-enable-or-disable-use-system-print-dialog-in-microsoft-edge/

Comment: No, because system print gives you a print preview dialog box also...

Comment: @Ramhound These methods used to disable the previews in Chrome and Firefox are specific to those programs.  They cannot just be transferred over to Edge

Comment: @TimothyBeckett - I was only trying to help, but in order to do that, I have to know the method you used for Chrome.